# Como obtener la diferencia de horas entre dos fechas JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estoy programando un calendario y tengo dos fechas que están en este formato:

end: Wed Dec 21 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (hora estándar de Europa central)

start: Tue Dec 20 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (hora estándar de Europa central)

como podría obtener la diferencia de horas?

He intentado pasar ese formato a horas normales pero no he conseguido nada.

Comment: ¿Cómo lo has intentado? ¿Has usado la clase Date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usando la clase Date puedes calcular la diferencia fácilmente:

```js
let t = new Date('Wed Dec 21 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0100');
let t2 = new Date('Tue Dec 20 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0100');

let diferenciaEnMilisegundos = t - t2;

console.log('diferencia', diferenciaEnMilisegundos);

console.log('Diferencia en horas', diferenciaEnMilisegundos / 3600000)
```

Comment: Recuerda no resolver las tareas de otros usuarios Pablo, a menos que demuestren haber realizado al menos un esfuerzo. Acá el tipo dice haber intentado algo, pero no lo ha mostrado, al menos que lo muestre.